# Change admin password for openfire version 4.0.2 from database

Tags: php, server, openfire

I have installed openfire in a live server. Which I forgot admin password. now I want to login into it. So, I manually changed password from database table ofuser as

```
username = admin
plainPassword = mypassword
encryptedPassword = NULL
name = Administrator
```

I am using firebase version 4.0.2. but I can't even login with my new password.

where is the problem?
Should I restart openfire server? 
Should I reinstall openfire on server?

Answer (score 1):

In case you change config files or database config you should restart openfire server, only changes from the admin panel can be done without restart.

If the problem persists, reinstall Openfire.

Remember to keep a backup of the correct database configuration of Openfire

Comment: I have only changed in database field value... Still I have to restart server?

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned above

Comment: can you please tell me which detail I require to restart openfire server?